Algorithm for Assigning Values to Variables According to a List of Conditions
I'm hoping to create a python script that will take a list of arbitrary relationships between arbitrary variables and assign integers to them that match all comparisons given, or tell you where some impossible logic exist if any is given.
Eg, the input:
A > B > C >= D
D > E
C > E * 2

Would return with D=1, C=1, B=2, A=3, E=0.
While A > B > C > A would simply tell you A > B and B > A can't both be true. Note that it should be able to recognize those types of cyclic dependencies that aren't with their immediate neighbors.
Does such an algorithm to do this with less trivial datasets already exist? I've spent a while looking for one myself but can't find anything closer to what I'm looking for than something that sorta sounds like it could be useful but ends up not actually being relevant.

it's called "linear programming": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

@MattTimmermans I'm not totally sure of that. Another experiment I tried before is setting all this up in a spreadsheet and using the "Solver", and aside from not being very practical on the scale I'm hoping for, one of the errors I got when using the linear solver was that what I was trying to do was "not linear". I don't know if that's because I actually had a cyclic dependency somewhere without knowing or if maybe it didn't like that I also wanted to do conditions with adding variables together because it wouldn't tell me anything else.

@PotatoCode linear programming requires that your objective function and conditions are linear combinations of the decision variables, if you are multiplying decision variables it will be non-linear. also, make a condition for each comparison. align multiple of the same comparisons so you can select a cell range instead of trying to add a condition for each row

This is also called "constraint propagation". I think sympy may be able to produce solutions.

@PotatoCode the examples you gave are linear, and you didn't describe any way in which your "real" requirements would not be.

This is an example of minimisation with constraints.
You want to minimise all the numbers subject to constraints like

A>0
B>0
A-B>=1
.....

(the answer to that would be A=1,B=0).
(The '>=1' is in case we use a continuous solver, so the answers come out as near-integers)
Your example was all linear, making this an easier, "linear minimisation" problem. You need to look back at your problem and decide if it will continue to be linear in the final case, if not this becomes a more difficult "nonlinear minimisation" problem.
Either way there are well documented algorithms for these optimisation problems, for example see scipy.optimize, which includes both linear and non-linear constraints.
